# How to update theme when device orientation changes

Tags: react-native, themes, device-orientation

I am trying to implement orientation changing with hooks. I called the orientation hook from app.tsx and I want to update everything(theme,style in component) that uses widthPercentageToDP() function. How can I achieve this. I can't figured out.

useOrientation.tsx

```
export let { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");

const heightPercentageToDP = (heightPercent: string | number): number => {
  // Parse string percentage input and convert it to number.
  const elemHeight =
    typeof heightPercent === "number"
      ? heightPercent
      : parseFloat(heightPercent);

  // Use PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel method in order to round the layout
  // size (dp) to the nearest one that correspons to an integer number of pixels.
  return PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel((height * elemHeight) / 100);
};

export const useScreenDimensions = () => {
  const [screenData, setScreenData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    setScreenData({orientation:currentOrientation()});

    Dimensions.addEventListener("change", (newDimensions) => {
     
      width = newDimensions.screen.width;
      height = newDimensions.screen.height;
      setScreenData({orientation:currentOrientation()}); // can be used with this height and width

      //console.log(newDimensions.window);
    });

    return () => Dimensions.removeEventListener("change", () => {});
  });

  return {
    
    width,height,
    screenData
  };
};
```

Theme file

```
const theme = {
  
    spacing: {
      m:widthPercentageToDP("2%") // it must be updated when orientation changes.
    },
    borderRadii: {
     s:widthPercentageToDP("5%") // it must be updated when orientation changes. 
    },
    textVariants: {
     body:{
       fontSize:widthPercentageToDP("%3"),
       
     }
    },
 
  };
```

App.tsx

```
 const {screenData} = useScreenDimensions();
 console.log(screenData)
  
 return (
    <ThemeProvider>
      <LoadAssets {...{ fonts, assets }}>
       <Example/>
      </LoadAssets>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Example.tsx

```
export const Example = ({}) => {

     
        return (
            <Box>
                <Text variant="body">hey</Text>

                {/* // it must be updated when orientation changes. */}
                <View style={{width:widthPercentageToDP("40%")}}/> 
                
            </Box>
        );
}
```

Box and theme come from theme.tsx file. Text component accepts variant prop that defined in theme.tsx

Answer (score 0):

Using [react-native-orientation](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation) you can do what you want, then the device orientation changes.

Example:

```
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation';

export default class AppScreen extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    const initial = Orientation.getInitialOrientation();
    if (initial === 'PORTRAIT') {
      // do something
    } else {
      // do something else
    }
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    // this will listen for changes
    Orientation.addOrientationListener(this._orientationDidChange);
  },

  _orientationDidChange = (orientation) => {
    if (orientation === 'LANDSCAPE') {
      // do something with landscape layout
    } else {
      // do something with portrait layout
    }
  },

  componentWillUnmount() {

    // Remember to remove listener to prevent memory leaks
    Orientation.removeOrientationListener(this._orientationDidChange);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but how can I update the value in theme ? Is it possible

Comment: @OğulcanKarayel, sorry, but it's friday and i'm at the work, so there's no way i'm going to read your entire code. 

You can try:

A global variable,
redux,
state,
props,
one line if statements